# How to inspect outgoing email content?

Tags: debugging, emails

There are several modules that send email from my site: Rules, Trigger, User, ...

I am looking for a place to set a `drupal_set_message()` and print out the email contents. Where in the code would be the best place for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`hook_mail_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7.x) to get, or alter, the content of an e-mail message before it's sent out.

```php
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) {
  dpm($message);
}
```

Not all modules use [`drupal_mail()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7), which means that for those modules `hook_mail_alter()` won't be invoked when they send an email.
In this case, you need to identify where in the module's code the mail is sent out, and see if they provide their own alter hooks. Look for any call to [`drupal_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/drupal_alter/7.x), [`module_implements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_implements/7.x), [`module_invoke()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_invoke/7.x), or [`module_invoke_all()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7.x).

Failing that, you may have to temporarily add the `dpm()` call directly to the module in the right place.